# Display popup page value in dropdown of parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have parent and popup page.
I have 2 `txtbox`, `Save` and `cancel` `button` in poppu page.
In popup page I entering data in `txtbox` nd click the `save button`.
Now I want to display the popup page 1st `txtbox` value into `dropdown` of parent page.

How can I achieve this....
Plz help me...

Comment: what have u tried for this? Are you using ajax?

Comment: what you are using for popup a new window or a `div` on the same page? Are you using database to save the data of popup?

Comment: is pop up page is a iframe or a div on the same page ?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.opener.document.getelementbyid("parentdropdownID")
```

By this you can get Drop down object of Parent page and then can assign value